# AWS with Serverless Framework EC2 deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

We are planning to deploy our API to AWS Lambda, and for local development, we use Serverless framework with Serverless Offline. Can we deploy the same serverless APP to dedicated server instances as we have some requirements where the same APP could be deployed in server as well. Can i use serverless-offline to run it. Or do we have any better mechanism . By the way we use Node JS.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends how you have your code setup, we use hapi to map the requests from lambda to a specific handler and we can also use hapi to run a server. The only effort that we had was to include a middleware to convert the lambda `event` to a request so that we can use the same handlers.
Here's something that we based our approach: 
http://www.carbonatethis.com/hosting-a-serverless-hapi-js-api-with-aws-lambda/

I wouldn't use serverless offline to be run in ec2 mainly because serverless offline does not work as a server and certain things don't work as expected when compared to lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the same APIs to Lambda also, For that you need to change your main index file. Or you can create 2 files let say index.js, server.js, where in index file simple Hapi/express code can be used and in server file, lambda function can be used. Routing will be the same for both files. You can use index.js for your local use and for lambda deployment you can use server.js.